# While (not) loop freezes app

Tags: objective-c, while-loop

My while loop doesn't seem to work. When loading this view, the app freezes.
When I delete the part of code, containing the while loop, the app won't freeze.

What I'm searching for is a piece of code that will cause that the same array is not chosen twice.

```
@interface ThirdViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThirdViewController

...
NSString * Answer = @"";
NSArray * RAMArray;

...

- (void)NewQuestion
{
    NSString * PlistString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Questions" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray * PlistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:PlistString];
    NSArray *PlistRandom = [PlistArray objectAtIndex: random()%[PlistArray count]];

    while (![PlistRandom isEqual: RAMArray])
    {
        NSArray *PlistRandom = [PlistArray objectAtIndex: random()%[PlistArray count]];
    }

    RAMArray = PlistRandom;
    ...
}

- (void)Check:(NSString*)Choise
{
    ...

    if ([Choise isEqualToString: Answer])
    {
        ...
        [self NewQuestion];
    }
}

- (IBAction)AnsButA:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *ResultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *Click = ResultButton.currentTitle;

    [self Check:Click];
}
```

Comment: it means the loop is infinite

Comment: by finding out what makes it infinite

Comment: If `RAMArray` is declared as a global elsewhere in the code, why do you declare a locale variable named `RAMArray` here? This local variable will hide the global. Also, inside your `while` loop, you declare a local `PlistRandom` variable. It is unused and it hides the `PlistRandom` variable declared before the loop.

Comment: I have to ask what is the point of that loop?  You keep selecting arrays from the plist array until you find one that is equal to RAMArray, then you are setting RAMArray to the array you have just found is equal to it.

Comment: @Maarten1909 What are `Answer` and `RAMArray` supposed to be? Right now they are file global variables. If they are supposed to be instance variables then you are declaring them incorrectly.

Comment: RAMArray is an extern Array, and Answer an extern String.
I use them both in multiple voids

Comment: That doesn't answer my question (I know their data types, that's obvious from the declaration). Instance variables can be used in any method of the class. But these aren't instance variables. These are file globals. This means that every instance of this class will share the single copy of each of those two variables. Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that because you re-declare `PlistRandom` within the while loop, the inner-declared variable may be out of scope at the point the `while` conditionis evaluated.  Your problem I think is a scoping issue, just change the loop to this and see if that works:

```
while (![PlistRandom isEqual: RAMArray])
{
    PlistRandom = [PlistArray objectAtIndex: random()%[PlistArray count]];
}
```

Comment: Good spot.  There's also the issue that RAMArray doesn't seem to be initialised anywhere.  If it's `nil` `isEqual:` sent to `PListRandom` will never be true.

Comment: @JeremyP Also a valid point, OP needs to specify if/where `RAMArray` is initialized

Comment: @rmaddy if you'd made your answer an answer instead of a comment, you could have had my up vote :)

Comment: Oops, this is correct but the view still freezes using this line of code. And without it, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Maarten1909 Do you ever initialize `RAMArray` anywhere?

Comment: @DanF I used this line before, i forgot to mention that.

if (RAMArray == nil) RAMArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"foo"];

Comment: Is `RAMArray` then inserted into `PlistArray`?

Comment: No, what i try to do is this:

PlistRandom is a random Array from PlistArray.
Then i save the value of PlistRandom into RAMArray.
After clicking a button, PlistRandom gets a new value (still an array from PlistArray) but if it is the same as the one that already was chosen before (and saved in RAMArray) then PlistRandom needs a new value until it is not the same as RAMArray

Comment: @Maarten1909 You need a completely different loop than the one you're using, and you are assigning what `PListRandom` gets TO `RAMArray` instead of adding values to it